# Map an array to an object, using array values as keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

I have

```
const menu = ['home', 'news', 'about'];
```

I want to map it to this:

```
let menuExt = 
 { 
  home: Common.locs['home'],
  news: Common.locs['news'],
  about: Common.locs['about'] 
 };
```

**How do I do that**? I tried

```
    let menuExt = menu.map(item => {
        return {
          item: Common.locs[item]
        }
    });
```

but I got an array with "item" as property, but I want one object with properties home, news, about... (there are many more but I shortened it here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
menu.map(item => {menuExt[item]=Common.locs[item]});
```

Comment: Bravo for the newcomer! The one-liner I was looking for, thanks! It works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks Hendry for your helpful answer. But please always add an explanation to answers even if it is only a brief one. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
. Otherwise, it gets popped onto the low quality queue and someone like me has to review it :) Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I managed this way, but I don't know if there is a cleaner and faster solution maybe:

```
    let menuExt = {}
    menu.forEach((item) => {
      menuExt[item] = Common.locs[item]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way would be to use `Array.reduce`, because you're taking an array of objects and returning a single object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```
const menu = ['home', 'news', 'about'];

const menuExt = menu.reduce((acc, key) => {
     acc[key] = Common.locs[key];
     return acc;
}, {});
```